# Syntax error when using auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql, I have a table with columns:

```
ID: INT(11) AUTO INCREMENT 
keyowner: VARCHAR(255)
key: VARCHAR(5)
```

and in php, I have following code:

```
<?php
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
}
$username = "root";
$host = "localhost";
$pass = "pass";
$db = "api";
$owner = get_client_ip();
$key1 = file_get_contents("afile");
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $pass, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "INSERT INTO api
      (key_owner, key)
      VALUES
      ($owner, $key1)";

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When the code is being run, it shows the error:

> > Error: INSERT INTO api (key_owner, key) VALUES (an_ip, OF580)
> >     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES (an_ip, afile)' at line 2

Comment: Shoudn't your $owner and $key1 be binded + qouoted with `'`???

Comment: if its autoincrement, your not supposed to provide it. just drop it from the field list and the values list

Comment: `('$owner', '$key1')`

Comment: You are so open to sql-injection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AS keyowner: varchar(255) key: varchar(5`) .You need to add `quotes` around your value to insert data and `key` is [reserver keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in `backtick`.

To prevent sql injection use `mysqli_real_escape_string` before insert into database

```
$key1  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$key1 );
$owner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $owner);
    $query = "INSERT INTO api
          (`key_owner`, `key`)
          VALUES
          ('".$owner."', '".$key1."')";
```

**Updated**

As your table name is `keys`. `keys` is also reserved keyword so you need backtick around it so the final query would be

```
$key1  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$key1 );
$owner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $owner);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `keys`
          (`key_owner`, `key`)
          VALUES
          ('".$owner."', '".$key1."')";
```

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO api (`key_owner`, `key`) VALUES ('46.177.69.117', 'xBVDh')
Table 'api.api' doesn't exist

Comment: Check table `api` is exist or not in your database?? what is your table name??

Comment: Sorry for that, but my table is "keys" and not "api" but it still not works.

Comment: My error: Error: INSERT INTO keys (`key_owner`, `key`) VALUES ('46.177.69.117', 'Bt0IC')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (`key_owner`, `key`) VALUES ('46.177.69.11' at line 1

Comment: Looks like "keys" is reserved word in mysql put it into ` symbols.

Comment: @ShuraKnows yes i suggested the same !!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that key is an SQL reserved word. So to use it as a column/table name    use backticks (`)

Also add quotes for values. Check the code below.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `api`
          (`key_owner`, `key`)
          VALUES
          ('$owner', '$key1')";
```

Comment: Fixed the problem with the wrong table name and it now works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you values should have a quotes, something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `api`
  (`key_owner`, `key`)
  VALUES
  ('$owner', '$key1')";
```

My advice to you is to use PHP PDO 
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.pdo.php)